# Need to import product image from Media library while updating product images

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, product, admin, image-upload

While uploading images for a product in Magento Admin panel, one can only upload/browse images from a local computer. Is there a way to have a Media Library ( *like the way we have in WordPress that can insert images into a post from the media library as well as upload images* ) that lists all the images that are already existing in the media folder of the Magento system, from which we can choose an image instead of choosing it from local computer.

This similar implementation can be seen in `CMS -> Content Pages -> <<Edit one of the page>> -> Insert Image` which lists the Media Storage. I want to implement a similar style for product images upload.

Also, any extensions already existing would also help me get over it. Please feel free to share any links to the custom extensions.

I prefer to have the solution in Magento 2, but a module in Magento 1 would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use media library to upload an image for product but if you want to import multiple images for products then you can do this via csv file.

If you want help with how to create csv file then you can check below blog:

[Import Multiple Product Images in Magento 2 Using CSV](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-import-images/)

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I'm actually looking for an alternative of using media library rather than upload files button on product images page in admin.